# How to take a first character from the string

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net & SQL Server 2005

```
Dim S as string
s = "Rajan"
s = "Sajan"
```

I want to take a first character from the string (s)

Expected Output

```
R
S
```

Need VB.Net Code Help

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this..

```
Dim S As String
S = "RAJAN"
Dim answer As Char
answer = S.Substring(0, 1)
```

Comment: While this does sorta work, it gives you a *string* containing the first char, rather than the char itself.  Basically, it's more work than necessary.

Comment: Getting error as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @Sam: A string is not a char, and a char is not a string.  If what you need is a char, then a string would need more glue (possibly inserted by VB, i forget) to convert it.  All in all, it's not worth it -- there's a way to get the chars directly, so that should be preferred if what you really want is a char.

Comment: Can't you use index notation? `S(0)`?

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
Dim s = "RAJAN"
Dim firstChar = s(0)
```

You can even do this:

```
Dim firstChar = "RAJAN"(0)
```

Comment: It's working, how to remove the first character, expected output : AJAN

Comment: @Gopal - Just do `"RAJAN".Substring(1)` to remove the first character.

Answer (score 8):

Use chars:

```
Dim firstChar As char;
firstChar = s.Chars(0);
```

http://vb.net-informations.com/string/vb.net_String_Chars.htm

Comment: Getting error as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @Gopal: That means your string variable doesn't have a string in it.  It's null.  The code here will work with the code you posted; your bigger problem is that you don't know what's in `s`.

Answer (score 1):

`"ABCDEFG".First` returns `"A"`

```
Dim s as string

s = "Rajan"
s.First
'R

s = "Sajan"
s.First
'S
```